# Paint event does not react

Tags: c#, winforms

I feel desperate, does somebody please have an idea, why i cannot fire Paint event? I tried all three methods (Invalidate, Update, Refresh) but nothing works.

Here is my whole super simple WinForm project.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public System.Windows.Forms.Timer movementTimer;

        public Form1()
        {
            movementTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            movementTimer.Interval = 10;
            movementTimer.Tick += tick;
            movementTimer.Start();
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Update();
            this.Refresh();
        }

        void tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Update();
            this.Refresh();
        }        

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // I cannot hit breakpoint here.
            Console.WriteLine("PAINT METHOD HAS BEEN EXECUTED");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the Form show? - Where did the InitializeComponent method go?

Comment: Now it works :-( InitializeComponent was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You broke something in the rest of the code that you're not showing. Try the following on an empty project, it works as expected:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 10 };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Paint += (s, e) => { };
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => Refresh();
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted all the project. You see all the code.

Comment: Then where did the `InitializeComponent()` method go?

Comment: Now it works :-( InitializeComponent was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here is your code... with some changes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Painter
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public System.Windows.Forms.Timer movementTimer;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            movementTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            movementTimer.Interval = 10;
            movementTimer.Tick += tick;
            movementTimer.Start();
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Update();
            this.Refresh();
        }

        void tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Update();
            this.Refresh();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // I cannot hit breakpoint here.
            Console.WriteLine("PAINT METHOD HAS BEEN EXECUTED");
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling Invalidate, Update AND Refresh? That doesn't do anything in a constructor, by the way, since the form isn't visible yet.  A Form doesn't have to subscribe to their own events.  Just use the OnPaint override.

Comment: dude... I just copied the ops code and got it to work... I didn't change anything he wrote.